# reading a div content from the main page when a modal is open

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I have a modal window that opens up when i click a link on the main page. on clicking a link in the modal window i want to read a particular divs content from the main page into the modal text area

I tried accessing it using

```
var val=$('div[data-mainid="'+res[2]+'"]').text();
```

it did not work ? are elements from the main page accessible via jquery event from a modal ?

Comment: *"...are elements from the main page accessible via jquery event from a modal ?"* Yes, [Bootstrap modals](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/modal/) are just elements positioned on top of other elements in the Z axis, they aren't `iframes` or otherwise out-of-document. If your code above didn't find anything, no element in the DOM matches the selector.

Comment: which is what i thought let me try something else...

Comment: Right now, your question can't be helpfully answered other than the comment above I'm afraid. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button); [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/). (Yes, Bootstrap and jQuery can be used in a Stack Snippet.)